# Sentry & Next.js 13.4: Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default. You may need an additional plugin to handle "c:" URIs

Tags: webpack, next.js, sentry

Hi I am currently experiencing this error:

```
- error C:devtestsentry.server.config.ts
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "C:devtestsentry.server.config.ts" is 
not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "c:" URIs.
Import trace for requested module:
C:devtestsentry.server.config.ts
./app/page.tsx
```

I have created an empty repo just to see if the error exists by default and yes.
I am using Windows. I created a new next repo with `npx create-next-app@latest` and then manually installed Sentry via `npm install --save @sentry/nextjs` and created the files described in their documentation:
`sentry.client.config.ts`, `sentry.server.config.ts`, `sentry.edge.config.ts`
Then added the changes `next.config.js` to include Sentry:

```
const { withSentryConfig } = require("@sentry/nextjs");

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

module.exports = withSentryConfig(nextConfig);
```

It seems that Webpack for some reason doesn't know how to deal with these sentry config files but I am not sure how to change the config in next/webpack to do so.

I couldn't find anything recent that shows this error and help would be more than welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was flagged as a bug in Sentry itself, you can see the issue here:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/8133

A Merge Request has been created and merged which will be released on (probably) the next version of Sentry. In the meantime you can use something like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to fix your installed package of `@sentry/nextjs` by adding the code in the merge request:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/pull/8142